# spring <form:checkboxes> tag and css class

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have issue with:

```
<form:checkboxes path="roles" cssClass="checkbox" items="${roleSelections}" />
```

If previous line is used in jsp, then generated html looks like:

```
<span><input id="roles1" name="roles" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="ROLE_NEWUSER"/><label for="roles1">ROLE_NEWUSER</label></span>
<span><input id="roles2" name="roles" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="ROLE_USER" checked="checked"/><label for="roles2">ROLE_USER</label></span>
<span><input id="roles3" name="roles" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="ROLE_EDITOR"/><label for="roles3">ROLE_EDITOR</label></span>
<span><input id="roles4" name="roles" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/><label for="roles4">ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR</label></span>
```

Please notice that css class is added to input tag. Instead css class is added to input tag I need this class to be added to span tag. Is there any solution to my problem, other then using `< c:forEach >` tag

Thanks in advance. Sorry if question is duplicate. If so, please point me to original question.

Cheers,
Tihomir

P.S.:

I'm using spring 3.1.0.RELEASE.

Comment: why don't you want to use `forEach`?

Comment: I hoped that there is shorter way then writing foreach loop. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${roleSelections}">
    <span class="checkbox"><form:checkbox path="roles" value="${item}"></span>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: at moment this is not option, because roleSelections is array of strings.

Comment: if your `item` is a string you can use simply `${item}`

Answer (score 24):

All you need to do is to specify 'element' attribute :

```
<form:checkboxes path="roles" element="span class='checkbox'" items="${roleSelections}" />
```

This will enclose each "input" tag and "label" tag in span with class 'checkbox'.

Comment: This is the better answer. Most probably you wanted the checkboxes displayed each in it's own line. In that case, attribute element="div" is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Without forEach loop, you can try below code

Define css for example

```
<style type="text/css">
            div {
                padding-left: 10px;
                background-color: #00ae42;
            }
        </style>
```

And then in your code remove "cssClass" attribute of checkboxes use "element" attribute. and for this element attribute you have already specified css above.
Ex.

```
<form:checkboxes path="roles" element="div" items="${roleSelections}" />
```

Refer below link for Spring MVC checkboxes attributes
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.checkboxes

Comment: this will not help, since there is a lot of div tags in that view. Any way thanks for pointing me on documentation. I think that this will help in future.